# I want make app intro animation through json api

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to make app intro animation like sliding intro, that sliding page have one image view & text view. Those image and text can be get by **'j-s-o-n'**  API. How to do it?
Please help me. I don't know that, but I want to learn...

Here is layout:

[image]

Comment: ImageLoader class has constructor with Context parameter ?

Comment: i m new one on android studio.i don't know that.sorry.but i want to learn. how to get image from json data.can you please explain me???.i also created json file (http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cqsVKyAjci?indent=2) through online.

Comment: In json data you get the url right ? use  http://square.github.io/picasso/ to load image

Comment: did you get value for "image_url"?

Comment: yes.i get this code from internet.i just retrive image and text from json data.how can i do it in sliding screen.like(https://github.com/paolorotolo/AppIntro).i want to replace static image on this link to change json image & text

Comment: Use this picasso lib for load image

Comment: i try that.but don't expect that.i want retrive the data(image & text) in json file to display sliding intro screen

Comment: what you exactly want to do ?

Comment: you can talk in hindi it will be better

Comment: appintro like three xml files combine into one java file.i don't know how to add it.

Comment: download that appintro code first

Comment: sorry i only know Tamil & little bit english.sorry.i give link(https://github.com/paolorotolo/AppIntro).i want this app intro.but i fetch the image and text from json api

Comment: i already download it.and i also run it.it run what i default design.but i want replace default image into webimage & default text into web text

Comment: thanks for your help